noUiSlider overlaps with elements below it which causes interaction issues
I am using noUiSlider for a project where I have multiple sliders on top of another. I noticed that the HTML elements lose interactivity if there is a slider on top of it and after a lot of digging I realised it's because the pips element overlaps with the slider below it.
I tried a bunch of CSS commands to change the z-index (after setting position to something non-static) but none of them worked. I also tried changing the height of the slider to compress it (including with !important), but all of those seem to get overwritten by the libraries' code.
I have temporarily added 5 <br> which seems to have worked, but since I have many sliders the section now takes up too much space which is why I was hoping to find a different work around.
I suspect the noUi-pips noUi-pips-horizontal class to be the main culprit but none of my CSS tags targeting that seem to be able to override the height. Any help/insight is appreciated!

Use pointer-events, namely:
.noUi-pips {
  pointer-events: none;
}


Thank you so much! Literally crying tears of joy because I spent HOURS trying to find a solution.
On a different note would you also happen to know if it's possible to have 2 sliders side by side (next to each other)? I wasn't able to find any material on that either. Thanks again!

Hello! I was glad to help! 2 sliders side by side - of course it is possible. Create a separate question with an example of your code and the desired result and I will help you.

Thank you! I asked a different question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78369399/placing-nouisliders-beside-each-other). Thanks again.
