Placing noUiSliders beside each other
I am trying to place 2 noUiSliders to the right of 3 other sliders since having multiple sliders takes up too much vertical space. My HTML page has 4 main tabs, and this all within a single tab, where I have one main collapsible header (Filters), which has further collapsible headers based on the type of filter ( Filters -> Phenotypic Data Filters)
I have 5 sliders in the Phenotypic Data Filters header which has an additional div called .slidercontainer because I wanted to restrict the width of the slider. Additionally each input header is linked to the Help tab which is what the href and onclick() functions are for.
I have tried setting up 2 different div for the slider (one with 3 and one with 2), with the purpose of trying to move the div with 2 sliders to the right, but I tried many ways and nothing seems to have worked.
My code is messy so please excuse that and it is below for reference:
Relevant CSS:
.collapsible {
            background-color: #777;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 12px;
            width: auto;
            border: 1px solid ;
            text-align: left;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 15px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .collapsible.active, .collapsible:hover {
            background-color: #555;
        }
        .collapsible::before {
            content: "\25BA";
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .active.collapsible::before {
            content: "\25BC";
        }
        .content {
            padding: 0 18px;
            display: none;
            border: 1px solid ;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }
.slidecontainer {
            width: 50%;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }


HTML:
<div class="collapsible">Phenotypic Data Filters</div>
                <div class="content">
                    <button id="reset_all_sliders" class="reset-all-button">Reset ALL Sliders</button>
                    <br>
                        <a href="#" onclick="openTab(event, 'help', 'help_year')" style = "margin-left:10px;" id="year_help"> Year: </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="year" value="2015" checked> 2015
                        <input type="checkbox" name="year" value="2016"> 2016
                        <input type="checkbox" name="year" value="2017"> 2017
                        <input type="checkbox" name="year" value="2018"> 2018
                        <br><br>

                        <a href="#" onclick="openTab(event, 'help', 'help_location')" style = "margin-left:10px;" id="location_help">Location: </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="location" value="Channel-North"> Channel-North
                        <input type="checkbox" name="location" value="Channel-South"> Channel-South
                        <input type="checkbox" name="location" value="Creek-West"> Creek-West
                        <input type="checkbox"  name="location" value="Creek-East"> Creek-East
                        <br><br>

                        <a href="#" onclick="openTab(event, 'help', 'help_mortality')" style = "margin-left:10px;" id="mortality_help">Mortality: </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="mortality" value="Alive"> Alive
                        <input type="checkbox" name="mortality" value="Missing"> Missing
                        <input type="checkbox" name="mortality" value="Dead"> Dead
                        <input type="checkbox" name="mortality" value="New"> New
                        <br><br>
                        
                        <div class="slidecontainer">
                        <a href="#" onclick="openTab(event, 'help', 'help_eco_vol')" id="eco_vol_help">Ecological Volume (units):</a>
                        <button id="eco_vol_reset" class="reset-button">Reset slider</button>
                        <div id="eco_vol_value" class="hover-value"></div><br><br><br><br>
                        <div id="eco_vol"></div>
                        <br><br><br>

                        <a href="#" onclick="openTab(event, 'help', 'help_ln_eco_vol')" id="ln_eco_vol_help">Natural Log of Ecological Volume (units):</a>
                        <button id="ln_eco_vol_reset" class="reset-button">Reset slider</button>
                        <div id="ln_eco_vol_value" class="hover-value"></div><br><br><br><br>
                        <div id="ln_eco_vol"></div>
                        <br><br><br>

                        <a href="#" onclick="openTab(event, 'help', 'help_length')" id="length_help">Length (cm):</a>
                        <button id="length_reset" class="reset-button">Reset slider</button>
                        <div id="length_value" class="hover-value"></div><br><br><br><br>
                        <div id="length"></div>
                        <br><br><br>
                        
                        <a href="#" onclick="openTab(event, 'help', 'help_width')" id="width_help">Width (cm):</a>
                        <button id="width_reset" class="reset-button">Reset slider</button>
                        <div id="width_value" class="hover-value"></div><br><br><br><br>
                        <div id="width"></div>
                        <br><br><br>
                        
                        <a href="#" onclick="openTab(event, 'help', 'help_height')" id="height_help">Height (cm):</a>
                        <button id="height_reset" class="reset-button">Reset slider</button>
                        <div id="height_value" class="hover-value"></div><br><br><br><br>
                        <div id="height"></div>
                        <br><br><br>
                    </div>
                </div>

noUiSlider code:
// Sliders
        var ecoVolSlider = document.getElementById('eco_vol');
        var ecoVol_field = document.getElementById('eco_vol_value');
        var lnEcoVolSlider = document.getElementById('ln_eco_vol');
        var lnVol_field = document.getElementById('ln_eco_vol_value');
        var alleleFreqSlider = document.getElementById('allele_freq');
        var allele_field = document.getElementById('allele_freq_value');
        var lengthSlider = document.getElementById('length');
        var length_field = document.getElementById('length_value');
        var widthSlider = document.getElementById('width');
        var width_field = document.getElementById('width_value');
        var heightSlider = document.getElementById('height');
        var height_field = document.getElementById('height_value');

        noUiSlider.create(ecoVolSlider, {
            start: [0],
            tooltips: true,
            connect: 'lower',
            behaviour: 'hover-snap',
            range: {
                'min': 0,
                'max': 35000
            },
            pips: {
                mode: 'values',
                values: [0, 10000, 20000, 30000, 35000],
                density: 4
            }
        });
        ecoVolSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
            ecoVol_field.innerHTML = values[handle];
            ecoVol_field.style.display = 'none';
        });
        
        noUiSlider.create(lnEcoVolSlider, {
            start: [0],
            tooltips: true,
            connect: 'lower',
            behaviour: 'hover-snap',
            range: {
                'min': -4,
                'max': 12
            },
            pips: {
                mode: 'values',
                values: [-4, 0, 4, 8, 12],
                density: 4
            }
        });
        lnEcoVolSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
            lnVol_field.innerHTML = values[handle];
            lnVol_field.style.display = 'none';
        });

        noUiSlider.create(lengthSlider, {
            start: [0],
            tooltips: true,
            connect: 'lower',
            behaviour: 'hover-snap',
            range: {
                'min': 0,
                'max': 50
            },
            pips: {
                mode: 'values',
                values: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                density: 4
            }
        });
        lengthSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
            length_field.innerHTML = values[handle];
            length_field.style.display = 'none';
        });
        
        noUiSlider.create(widthSlider, {
            start: [0],
            tooltips: true,
            connect: 'lower',
            behaviour: 'hover-snap',
            range: {
                'min': 0,
                'max': 50
            },
            pips: {
                mode: 'values',
                values: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                density: 4
            }
        });
        widthSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
            width_field.innerHTML = values[handle];
            width_field.style.display = 'none';
        });
        
        noUiSlider.create(heightSlider, {
            start: [0],
            tooltips: true,
            connect: 'lower',
            behaviour: 'hover-snap',
            range: {
                'min': 0,
                'max': 25
            },
            pips: {
                mode: 'values',
                values: [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
                density: 4
            }
        });
        heightSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
            height_field.innerHTML = values[handle];
            height_field.style.display = 'none';
        });

Thank you in advance for your help and I appreciate any input!

Please provide a minimal reproducible example of the problem
